# Adaptive Icon not working

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="..."
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    tools:replace="icon,label,theme,name,allowBackup">
```

under the folder `mipmap-anydpi-v26` I have defined `ic_launcher.xml`:

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <background android:drawable="@color/white"/>
   <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

here is my folder structure :
[image]

build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
targetSdkVersion = 25
minSdkVersion = 18
```

AND, I'm using android studio 3.0

but the end result is that I get a default android icon instead of the one I provided.

I've also tried putting the foreground png in all of the density folders (mipmap-xhdpi, etc), although I used the same png for all when I did this just for testing

Comment: Are you using simulator or real device? If device, what kind?

Comment: Using emulator, nexus 5x on sdk 26

Comment: Hard to say... Have you tried to update build tools? Another thing is that emulator can not support icon variation.

Comment: @KarolKulbaka it was the build tools version, if you'd like, submit that as an answer, other wise I will

Comment: did you try to add this `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` to you `AndroidManifest`? take a look at this. [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html)

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51171446/2396539)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adaptive icon requied API 26 so you need to update your buildtools to at least 26.0.0 version

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful

Comment: I have the build tools set to 26.0.2 but it still show the default icon.

Comment: In Android Studio go to Help -> "Find action..." type "image asset" and click to open it. In there you can specify the foreground image, the background image(or color) and it will automatically generate all the launcher images and xml files.

Comment: @toobsco42 I had the same issue but it turned out to be because I mistakenly used the wrong xmls definition (basically I used what Android Studio suggested as the auto-fix, which was a bad idea in this case).

Comment: i dont see the requirements for the buildtools in the official documentation [https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive), where is this documented?

Comment: okey i think I got it, for anyone else having this doubt refer [https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)

Answer (score 6):

I too have faced the same issue, here is how I have fixed this issue

1. Right click on resource ->  New -> ImageAsset
2. Choose the ic_launcher_background icon and ic_launcher_foreground as shown in below screen

[image]

3. Android studio creates an ic_launcher.xml under resource **mipmap** (anydpi-v26)

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
       <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
   </adaptive-icon>
   ```
4. Now inside the Manifest.XML, declare the icon and round icon 
   something shown in like below

   ```
   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


                   .......</application>
   ```

   Yes that's all and Run your app on any device it appears

Comment: Yep.  I was using `drawable/ic_launcher` instead of `mipmap/ic_launcher`.  Not use often and I think not well documented.

Comment: Somewhat yeah we need to dig more get in details, https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Comment: Success. Yeah, if you replace your launcher icon you need to remember to replace your drawable for mipmap. This one got me good.

Comment: im using bubblewrap with VSC (npx bubblewrap init --manifest.... for a PWA), i removed all drawable folders, and i made a folder called mipmap-anydpi-v26, added the ic_launcher.xml, made myself some foreground and background png images with figma for each mipmap folder mdpi 48px, hdpi 72px....etc. and now the icon has a colored background no matter the icon shape on the phone

Answer (score 2):

I had issues getting my adaptive icon to display. Turns out I had done nothing wrong. It started working after I did a 'Clean Project' in Android Studio.

Comment: I had everything fine too. I was about to keep trying different configurations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ic_launcher.xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug it using an `<ImageView>`.  When I did so, I got a backtrace ending with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path string cannot be empty.
```

Turns out my `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` had some `<path>` elements with empty `android:pathData` attributes.

Deleting those empty `<path>`s made the icon work!